# Modifying TestAssert.h (cppunit) - why the order of includes matter for macro expansion?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, cppunit

I have a project which has two base exception classes; both have the same name, only the methods/members differ (one has a method which returns the message, the other has only a string member which can be accessed for info regarding the exception).

I'm using CPPUNIT for testing and in the framework there's the TestAssert.hpp file which contains macros for every assertion (CPPUNIT_ASSERT_NO_THROW, etc.). I've modified adding in it another macros which test what exception headers are included in the test classes, so I could catch my base exceptions; the macros look like this:

```
#ifdef BASE_EXCEPTION_CLASS_ONE_HPP
#define MY_CPPUNIT
catch (BaseException &ex) {
ex.getMessage();
}
#endif
#ifdef BASE_EXCEPTION_CLASS_TWO_HPP
#define MY_CPPUNIT
catch (BaseException &ex) {
cout << "Caught: " ex.comment <<endl;
}
#endif
```

these two macros will be then used like this in TestAssert.h

```
/** Asserts that the given expression does not throw any exceptions.
 * \ingroup Assertions
 * Example of usage:
 * \code
 *   std::vector<int> v;
 *   v.push_back( 10 );
 *  CPPUNIT_ASSERT_NO_THROW( v.at( 0 ) );
 * \endcode
 */
# define CPPUNIT_ASSERT_NO_THROW( expression )                             \
   try {                                                                   \
      expression;                                                          \
   } catch ( const std::exception &e ) {                                   \
      CPPUNIT_NS::Message message( "Unexpected exception caught" );        \
      message.addDetail( "Type: " +                                        \
                   CPPUNIT_EXTRACT_EXCEPTION_TYPE_( e,                     \
                                       "std::exception or derived" ) );    \
      message.addDetail( std::string("What: ") + e.what() );               \
      CPPUNIT_NS::Asserter::fail( message,                                 \
                                  CPPUNIT_SOURCELINE() ); }                \
    MY_CPPUNIT                                                             \
    catch ( ... ) {                                                        \
      CPPUNIT_NS::Asserter::fail( "Unexpected exception caught",           \
                                  CPPUNIT_SOURCELINE() );                  \
   }
```

This works, but only if in the test class the first #include is the #include "test.hpp"

So, how does the macro expansion is affected by the include order, or how could I see the preprocessing part so I can figured it out somehow?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just guessing, but the order of includes probably affects whether `BASE_EXCEPTION_CLASS_ONE_HPP` and `BASE_EXCEPTION_CLASS_TWO_HPP` are defined at the point where the `#ifdef`s look at them. But it's impossible to say for sure from this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `gcc -E` to see the output after the preprocessor. That includes all expanded macros and lets you see what happens with your macro expansion. You can also compile that file in the second step and get better error reporting if the problem was originally inside one of the macros.

Comment: I've used gcc with -save-temps, saw the order of the includes but then I had another approach to the problem, abandoned the macro idea and included try-catch blocks for all exception classes.